# 'flow property not found in props of react element' when is present for enzyme rendering of component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, flowtype, enzyme

**My Component:**

```
// @flow
import React from 'react'

type Props = {
  close: Function,
  name: string
}

const MyComponent = ({ close, name }: Props) => (
  <div className='click' onClick={close}>
    {name}
  </div>
)

export default MyComponent
```

**My Enzyme Test:**

```
// @flow
import React from 'react'
import assert from 'assert'
import { shallow } from 'enzyme'
import sinon from 'sinon'

import MyComponent from 'client/apps/spaces/components/slideouts/record-settings/myc'

const defaultProps = {
  close: () => {},
  name: 'My Name'
}

const render = (props) => shallow(<MyComponent {...defaultProps} {...props} />)

describe('<MyComponent />', () => {
  it('renders the name', () => {
    const component = render()

    assert.equal(component.find('.click').text(), 'My Name')
  })

  it('calls close on Click', () => {
    const close = sinon.spy()
    const component = render({ close })
    const clickableDiv = component.find('.click')
    clickableDiv.simulate('click')

    assert(close.calledOnce)
  })
})
```

The tests pass, but it is giving me the following flow error on my 'MyComponent' declaration which refers to the rendering line in my test, despite `name` definitely being passed in as part of the `defaultProps` object that is passed into the component:

> property 'name' Property not found in props of react element
>   'MyComponent'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, if I completely removed the second test, there was no flow error in the above as written.

I think the problem was that whenever I was passing something to the `render()` in my test file, flow only checked the overriding props on the component instead of all of them.

Rewriting my test render function like so solved my problem:

```
const render = (overrideProps) => {
  const props = {
    ...defaultProps,
    ...overrideProps
  }

  return shallow(<MyComponent {...props} />)
}
```